# How to connect Foxpro Database using Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, foxpro

I need to connect a Foxpro database using Hibernate. I searched on Google but didn't find anything like that. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Please Check the following links:

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SupportedDatabases2 
and
http://www.hxtt.com/hibernate.html